# How to get CameraPreview by AndroidView

Tags: android, android-camerax, android-jetpack-compose

I create the CameraPreview in layout resource file, and i want to show this file in AndroidView by clicking the navigation icon button .

```
// navigation icon button
Icon(
    vectorResource(id = R.drawable.ic_photo),
    modifier = Modifier.clickable(onClick = /* show CameraPreview */)
)

// compose CameraPreview
@Composable
fun CameraPreview() {
    val lifecycleOwner = LifecycleOwnerAmbient.current
    val context = ContextAmbient.current
    val cameraProviderFuture = remember { ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(context) }
    AndroidView(viewBlock = { ctx ->
        /* get the CameraPreview */
    })
}

// xml file
<androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/previewView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an instance of `PreviewView` in your composable itself:

```
@Composable
fun CameraPreview() {
    val lifecycleOwner = LifecycleOwnerAmbient.current
    val context = ContextAmbient.current
    val cameraProviderFuture = remember { ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(context) }

    val previewView = remember { PreviewView(context) }

    AndroidView(viewBlock = { previewView }) {
        // Initialize your camera here
    }
}
```

Comment: I post a issue related to initialize the camera https://stackoverflow.com/q/64620210/9768260.