# How to initialize camera in compose

Tags: android, android-camerax, android-jetpack-compose

I want to get a camera view by compose androidView, but the following code seems not work for me.

```
@Composable
fun CameraPreviewScreen() {
    val lifecycleOwner = LifecycleOwnerAmbient.current
    val context = ContextAmbient.current
    val cameraProviderFuture = remember { ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(context) }
    val previewView = remember { PreviewView(context) }
    AndroidView(viewBlock = { previewView }) {
        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(Runnable {
            val cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
            val preview = Preview.Builder().build()
            preview.setSurfaceProvider(it.surfaceProvider)
            val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA
            try {
                cameraProvider.unbindAll()
                cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                    lifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, preview)
            } catch(exc: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context))
    }
}
```

The snapshot below.
[image]

The report error.

> Permission Denial: can't use the camera
> cannot open camera "0" without camera permission (code 1)

Answer (score 0):

Since your problem seems related to camera permission, you can use [Permissions APIs](https://google.github.io/accompanist/permissions/) from [Accompanist](https://google.github.io/accompanist/) library to ask the user for permissions.

The docs show an example with camera

```kotlin
@Composable
private fun FeatureThatRequiresCameraPermission(
    navigateToSettingsScreen: () -> Unit
) {
    // Track if the user doesn't want to see the rationale any more.
    var doNotShowRationale by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }

    val cameraPermissionState = rememberPermissionState(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    PermissionRequired(
        permissionState = cameraPermissionState,
        permissionNotGrantedContent = {
            if (doNotShowRationale) {
                Text("Feature not available")
            } else {
                Column {
                    Text("The camera is important for this app. Please grant the permission.")
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
                    Row {
                        Button(onClick = { cameraPermissionState.launchPermissionRequest() }) {
                            Text("Ok!")
                        }
                        Spacer(Modifier.width(8.dp))
                        Button(onClick = { doNotShowRationale = true }) {
                            Text("Nope")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        permissionNotAvailableContent = {
            Column {
                Text(
                    "Camera permission denied. See this FAQ with information about why we " +
                        "need this permission. Please, grant us access on the Settings screen."
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
                Button(onClick = navigateToSettingsScreen) {
                    Text("Open Settings")
                }
            }
        }
    ) {
        Text("Camera permission Granted")
    }
}
```